# OpenIddictAuthorizations.CreationDate is always null

Tags: openiddict

OpenIddict v3.0.3

When rows are added to the table OpenIddictAuthorizations, the column CreationDate is never populated.

Refering to model class OpenIddictEntityFrameworkAuthorization.CreationDate.

https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/750f8422733f7a74cbbf9769a18ad08900ebecf5/src/OpenIddict.EntityFramework.Models/OpenIddictEntityFrameworkAuthorization.cs

What could be missing? Any hint is appreciated.

Our implementation of OpenIddict has been upgraded during development when OpenIddict has been updated, so something may be missed along the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the creation date to the descriptor when using the overload accepting an `OpenIddictAuthorizationDescriptor` instance.

That said, I opened https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/1247 to update the other overload to populate the creation date automatically.